# Slack - confirm before send

Tags: slack

Is there a way, by means of some setting or programmatically, to allow a user on Slack to confirm that the user really wants to send a message before the message is sent? Often times we end up sending messages on the wrong channels or DMs. How can we prevent these?

Comment: See my answer below. But to me this sounds more like something that should be addressed with better training of your people on how to use Slack.

Comment: That would be a great feature request for Slack. We also need it to prevent people posting directly to a channel instead of replying in a thread to a previous message in the channel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming by "send a message" you mean "post a message" to a channel.

### Via Settings

No. There is no Slack setting to enable confirmation before a message is posting.

### Programmatically

No. Its possible to retrieve all messages that are posted to a channel with a Slack app (e.g. via [Events API](https://api.slack.com/events-api)) and then react to them, but only after the fact. To the best of my knowledge it is not possible to insert some kind of confirmation logic into the standard process of posting a message.

Comment: Title on the green button with arrow on it says "Send now", and not "Post now"